# Why is this map an isomorphism?

Tags: commutative-algebra

In Altman-Kleinman "Introduction to Grothendieck Duality Theory", page 105, there is the following Lemma[image]:

I don't understand why by uniqueness, I can conclude $w \circ w'=id$. Any help?

Comment: Can you describe the notations? E.g. what is $\Omega^1_{A/k}$? Anyways, typically, both $w\circ w'$ and ${\rm id}$ will satisfy a given universal property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $d:A \rightarrow \Omega$ is a $K$-derivation there is a *unique* morphism $w‘: \Omega_{A\mid K}^1 \rightarrow \Omega$ satisfying $w’ \circ d_{A\mid K} = d‘$ by the universal property of the module of Kähler-differentials.

As $d_{A\mid K}$ is a derivation as well, there is a *unique* morphism $i: \Omega_{A\mid K}^1 \rightarrow \Omega_{A\mid K}^1$ satisfying $i \circ d_{A\mid K} = d_{A\mid K}$. Note that the identity is such a morphism, hence $i = id$.

Finally we are given a morphism $w: \Omega \rightarrow \Omega_{A\mid K}$ satisfying $w \circ d = d_{A\mid K}$. Hence we can calculate
$$w \circ w‘ \circ d_{A\mid K} = w \circ d = d_{A\mid K}$$
which shows that $w \circ w‘$ satisfies the universal property of $\Omega_{A\mid K}$, so again by uniqueness we find
$$w \circ w‘ = i = id.$$